# Disable multi frame images from "playing" by default

Tags: images

How can one globally disable multi-frame animated graphic files (gif, tiff, etc.) from playing?

Multi-frame images, for example animated GIFs, play by default. I would like to globally disable that function in my config while retaining the ability to use in-line images in ERC, org-mode, etc.

The desired effect of disabling such images' auto-play function is to show the file's first frame only.

I found `image-toggle-animation`, but it doesn't seem to do what I want.

I use Emacs 24.4.1.